# how to start input number as decimal format from right to left by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

If the user inputs a number in the text box, it should format as given below scenario.

1. Key in 1 -> 0.01
2. Key in 2 -> 0.12
3. Key in 3 -> 1.23

Next is backspace, If the user press backspace.

4. Backspace -> 0.12

Comment: Your question is very unclear! Edit it before someone closes it...

Comment: i understand the quesiton - just wondering what you have tried? Basically you need to divide the inputted number by 100 and display to 2 decimal places

Comment: Input for amount or currency entry fields should start from right to left at decimal places

Comment: this is a need to act as a string, if we divide the given input as a decimal it will be added to the value. something the logic should work shift right to left the inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer using simple javascript,

```
    var temp = "";
    var temp2 = "1.23";                       //input box value
    var input = "4";                          //input key in value
    temp = parseInt(temp2.replace(/\D/g,'')); //replace the specail char 
    var finalVal = temp+input;                // add like string and format it
    console.log("Formatted: "+ finalVal/100); // 12.34
```

Answer (score 1):

use can use this regex to achieve the goal.

```
    $('#money').on('keyup', function () {
            let val = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''))/100
            val = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val
            $(this).val(val)
        })
```